# Kähler potential in $\Bbb C^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I wanted to check that $\varphi\colon \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb R$ given by $$\varphi(z^1,\ldots, z^n) = \log\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |z^k|^2 + 1 \right)$$is a Kähler potential. One can compute $$\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial \overline{z}^k}(z^1,\ldots, z^n) = \frac{z^k}{\sum_{k=1}^n |z^k|^2 + 1}$$and so $$\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial z^j \partial \overline{z}^k}(z^1,\ldots, z^n) = \frac{\delta^k_{\;j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |z^k|^2 + 1 \right) - \overline{z}^jz^k}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |z^k|^2 + 1 \right)^2}.$$It is easy to see that the matrix $(\partial^2\varphi/\partial z^j\partial \overline{z}^k)_{j,k=1}^n$ is Hermitian, but I don't have a clue of how to check that it is positive definite. Sylvester's criterion seems awful to apply here. Help?

Comment: So you don't want to check just that $\sqrt{-1}\partial\bar\partial\varphi$ is a positive $(1,1)$-form?

Comment: Isn't it exactly the same thing? Or is there a definition for "positive form" I'm not aware? It looks like $$\frac{i}{2}\partial\overline{\partial}\varphi 
= \frac{i}{2} \sum_{j,k=1}^n \frac{\delta^k_{\;j}\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |z^k|^2 + 1 \right) - \overline{z}^jz^k}{\left(\sum_{k=1}^n |z^k|^2 + 1 \right)^2}\,{\rm d}z^j\wedge {\rm d}\overline{z}^k.$$

Comment: To determine whether a $(1,1)$-form is positive doesn't require looking at minors of all sizes of the hermitian matrix! It just suffices (modulo signs) to consider $\omega(v,\bar v)$ for arbitrary holomorphic tangent vector $v$, as I recall.

Comment: I guess, on slight thought, that is just positive definiteness of the hermitian matrix. I don't think you want to use Sylvester's criterion, though.

Comment: Yes, I guess it would be equivalent... because if $\omega = (i/2) \sum_{j,k} h_{jk} \,{\rm d}z^j\wedge {\rm d}\overline{z}^k$ and $v = \sum_k a^k \partial_{z^k} + b^k \partial_{\overline{z}^k}$, then $$\omega(v,Jv) = \sum_{j,k}h_{jk} a^jb^k.$$I tried computing that for this case but it still wasn't very nice.

Comment: Ah, and your claim about $\omega(v,\bar{v})$ for holomorphic vectors is equivalent to positiveness of $b_{jk} = i h_{jk}/2$ instead of $h_{jk}$ (but it was a nice exercise to check that, I didn't knew that result)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if you take $v = \sum a^k\frac{\partial}{\partial z^k}$, then let's denote by $\alpha=(a^1,\dots,a^n)$ and $z=(z^1,\dots,z^n)\in\Bbb C^n$ and by $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ the standard Hermitian inner product on $\Bbb C^n$.
\begin{align*}
\big(1+\sum_k |z^k|^2\big)^2\sum\frac{\partial^2\varphi}{\partial z^j\partial\bar z^k}(v,\bar v) &= \sum_j |a^j|^2\big(1+\sum_k|z^k|^2\big) - \sum_{j,k} a^j\bar a^k z^k\bar z^j \\
&= \langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle + \langle\alpha,\alpha\rangle\langle z,z\rangle - \langle\alpha,z\rangle\langle z,\alpha\rangle.
\end{align*}
By Cauchy-Schwarz, $\langle\alpha,z\rangle\langle z,\alpha\rangle = |\langle\alpha,z\rangle|^2\le \|\alpha\|^2\|z\|^2$, and so the sum is positive unless $\alpha=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was clever! It seems that the denominator $(\|z\|^2 + 1)^2$ is missing there, but fortunately it does not have any input on positiveness, so it's pretty good to me :)

Comment: Oops. Yeah, it's irrelevant, but I should make things correct.